# Best data structure to store jSessionId and userId

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to store pairs like `<jSessioId, userId>`. jSessionId is unique but userId not unique (multiply login).

I need to perform following operations:

```
 void add(jSessioId, userId)
 userId getUserId(jSessionId)
 void removeByJSessionId (jSessionId)
 Set<userId> getAllUserId()
```

I was trying to use `HashMap<jSessioId, userId>` but in this case `getAllUserId()` requires to convert values to set every time i request this data. I was trying to use additional set to store userId, but this also doesn't look fine for me because of a lot additional code.

I wonder what is the best solution to store such kind of data.

**UPDATE
Use cases for methods :

- `add` - login operations
- `getUserId` - every request operation
- `removeBySessionId` - logout / session listener
- `getAll` - used a lot in different place of the code

In current solution I am performing `add` operations both to hashmap and set. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Can you give us some context where and when you will be performing these operations?

Comment: void add(jSessioId, userId) - user login

userId getUserId(jSessionId) - every request

void removeByJSessionId (jSessionId) - session listener on destroy / logout

Set<userId> getAllUserId() - very often in different place of the code

Comment: Depends on how often getAllUserId is called, whether a sorted `map.values()` suffices (`O(N log N)`). (One may suppose that multiple logins are rare, if the session timeout is small enough and the application not permanently losing the session.)

Comment: What is wrong with just using `Map.values()` for `getAllUserId()`?

Comment: in case of use `Map.values()` i will get a lot of duplicate userId values

Comment: `getAllUserId` calls very often and the collection size is pretty big that the reason why i require better solution then just converting to set.

Comment: Why? You don't need a data structure at all. Both these things are already in the current HttpSession.

Comment: And how in that case you will maintain all active user ids, you can't determine when to delete user id from logged user set. Because even with session end, you can't be sure that the user is offline because of possible multiply login.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of this interface you're describing?

Comment: To me it seems quite impossible that `new HashSet<>(map.values())` would have any performance impact compared to whatever you are doing later with such a large set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set userIds = new HashSet(Map.values());`

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps maintain 2 data structures?

void add(jsessionId, userId) would add both of those parameters to a HashMap as you're doing now and also add the userId to a set?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, this is my current solution but I was thinking that maybe there is a better one.